# How do weapon modifiers stack with other bonuses in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

If I have a weapon with a +X% damage modifier (e.g. Ruthless) while also having +Y% total other damage bonuses (from accessories, buffs, etc...), will the total damage be:

Multiplicative: `(BaseDamage * (100% + X%)) * (100% + Y%)`
**OR**
Additive: `BaseDamage * (100% + X% + Y%)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Based on the information in the wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Damage_types#Calculations), it appears to be additive.

> A weapon's damage stat is determined cumulatively such as:
>
> Base damage * [1 + Weapon modifier/100 + (Head + Chest + Legs + Set bonus)/100 + (Accessory1 + Accessory2 + Acessory3 + Accessory4 + Accessory5 + AccMod1 + AccMod2 + AccMod3 + AccMod4 + AccMod5)/100]
>
> For example, Godly Dao of Pow with Turtle Armor, Menacing Warrior emblem, Menacing Avenger emblem, Menacing Destroyer Emblem, Menacing Mechanical Glove and Menacing Celestial Stone equipped:

```
50 * [1 + 15/100 + (6+8+0+0)/100 + (15+12+10+12+10+4+4+4+4+4)/100]
 = 50 * [1 + 15/100 + 14/100 + 79/100]
 = 50 * [1 + .15 + .14 + .79]
 = 50 * 2.08
 = 104
```

> Note: Damage always rounds to the nearest whole number, which alters modifiers' percentages accordingly. It rounds down for .5 damage or less and up for anything above .5 damage.

Comment: I actually remember reading that very page at one point, it's how I knew bonuses stacked additively amongst themselves. I didn't remember it also mentioned modifiers, as it turns out it does. Thanks.